# Is using setTimeout(fn, 0) to defer code execution until after the current call stack reliable?

Tags: javascript

I've got a function that is called an unknown number of times. I need to know how many times the function was run so I'm doing:

```
(function () {    

    var i = 0,
        increment = function () {
            if (i === 0) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    console.log('increment was called ' + i + ' times.'); // increment was called 3 times.
                    i = 0;
                }, 0);
            }
            i++;
        };

    increment();
    increment();
    increment();

})();
```

Can anyone tell me whether this is reliable across all browsers or whether there's a better pattern to achieve this?

Comment: Interesting design, although I would make the timeout for at least 13 ms because some browsers treat numbers too low as 0 and **may** run it right away, don't quote me on that though

Comment: Yes, it's reliable, noting that a specified delay of less than 4ms will be rounded up to 4ms in all modern browsers as per the html5 spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeout()` places a function on the queue, which is executed when all the other functions have been run.

If you call `setTimeout()` a few times before calling `increment()`, you will probably notice the `i` variable reaching a value greater than 1.

Comment: How do you have two answers?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this code snippet seems to be reliable across all browsers even in the lowest version of IE. I tried this in IE8 I works good.